# Angular2 (2.0.0-beta.17) NgSwitchWhen gives "No provider for TemplateRef!"

Tags: typescript, angular, ng-switch

I've been stumped by this for a fair few hours now. It's time for one of you guys to tell me what I'm doing wrong :)

The below component fails with 'No provider for TemplateRef!'. A plunker is available [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9SY56eUku7m7XSf66XZ6?p=preview). I got the ngSwitch syntax from [here](https://angular.io/cheatsheet#!#stq=ngswitch&stp=1).

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
//This should make the NgSwitch family available, right?
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common'
// I get same result with explicit import
// import {NgSwitch,NgSwitchWhen} from '@angular/common' 

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div [ngSwitch]="switchValue">
        <div ngSwitchWhen="42">It's 42!</div>
        <div ngSwitchWhen="21">It's 21!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
  // directives: [NgSwitch,NgSwitchWhen]
})
export class App {
  switchValue = 42;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the short syntax with implicit `<template>` you need to add `*`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div [ngSwitch]="switchValue">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="42">It's 42!</div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="21">It's 21!</div>
        <!-- before RC.2 
          <div *ngSwitchWhen="42">It's 42!</div>
          <div *ngSwitchWhen="21">It's 21!</div>
        -->
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  switchValue = 42;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
  }
}
```

See also [NgSwitch directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html)

Comment: My hero! I had already tried various combinations of [..] and *.., but not the one you suggested :) I am just now learning angular2, so I haven't quite familiarized myself with the explicit and implicit <template> thing.. I'll get there, though. Thanks a bunch!